# asp:Button Click event not being fired

Tags: asp.net, button, event-handling

I am dynamically adding rows in an asp table. In each row of the table I am also including a button which has a SelectProduct_Click event.

The problem is that even though I am registering the click event, the event is not being fired.

The button is being added in this way:

```
btnSelect = new Button();
btnSelect.ID = "btnSelect";
btnSelect.CommandArgument = od.ProductId;
btnSelect.Click += new EventHandler(this.SelectProduct_Click);
btnSelect.CssClass = "button";
btnSelect.Text = "Select";
cell = new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(btnSelect);
row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

How can I get my button to fire on click?

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn about the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

In order for dynamic controls to fire their events on postback, they need to be recreated and attached to the event handler again.

The best place to create (and re-create) dynamic controls is in the `OnInit` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

@Oded - you are absolutely right about the right timing to add dynamic controls. However it is not written on which event he is trying to add the button.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. I am adding the button in a method which is called when the user clicks on a particular button named Show List. As I need that the buttons are created after the user clicks the Show List button I'm not sure if I can call such method (which creates the buttons) in the OnInit section.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Couldn't you create the button in the OnInit event but hide it. Then when the Show List button is clicked just show the hidden button. :/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will use a gridview and use the gridviews's select record button instead.. as I needed the button to select a certain record.