# How do add an EventHandler for a dynamically generated Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling

This is very similar to these questions, but they didn't seem to help me (will explain why below):

- [How to create an onClick eventHandler for a dynamically created button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900257/how-to-create-an-onclick-eventhandler-for-a-dynamically-created-button)
- [asp.net dynamically button with event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713242/asp-net-dynamically-button-with-event-handler)
- [asp:Button Click event not being fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779040/aspbutton-click-event-not-being-fired)

I'm creating a C# aspx page. That page grabs a bunch of data and then builds a table out of it. One of the columns in the table contains a button that gets dynamically created as it builds the data (since the button's action relies on the data in the table).

Default.aspx

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Table ID="tblData" runat="server"></asp:Table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Defafult.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Build_Table();
    }

protected void Build_Table()
    {
        //create table header row and cells
        TableHeaderRow hr_header = new TableHeaderRow();
        TableHeaderCell hc_cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        hc_cell.Text = "This column contains a button";
        hr_header.Cells.Add(hc_cell);
        tblData.Rows.Add(hr_header);

        //create the cell to contain our button
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell_with_button = new TableCell();

        //create the button
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn1_Click);

        //add button to cell, cell to row, and row to table
        cell_with_button.Controls.Add(btn1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell_with_button);
        tblData.Rows.Add(row);
    }

protected void btn1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do amazing stuff
    }
```

Here's where I'm tripping up. I understand that my EventHandler isn't being fired because it needs to be moved over to the Page_Load method. However, if I move the btn1 creation and EventHandler over to Page_Load, I can no longer access them in Build_Table!

All of the code examples I see either have btn1 statically added in the ASPX page, or have it dynamically created in Page_Load. What's the best way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I ran your code and it works, event handler fires no problem. Have your verified that your handler is firing, but something bad is happening while it is doing "amazing stuff"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your buttons with an ID before you bind the event:

```
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.ID = "btnMyButton";
btn1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn1_Click);
```

Make sure every button has an unique ID. Also, I would personally move the code to `Page_Init` instead of `Page_Load`.